# Changing matplotlib font type

Tags: matplotlib

Hi I want to change the matplotlibrc file settings for a package called deepTools, so its plots use Helvetica - but having some trouble locating the matplotlibrc file that corresponds to that python tool package? Any ideas would be much appreciated, thanks.

I have tried:

'>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'

'>>> plt.style.use('ggplot')'

'>>>print(plt.style.available)'

As well as ggplot I tried to toggle to some of the others in

'plt.style.available'

However it does not seem to change in the output of the python tool I am using, which is

'importing matplotlib'

Comment: Is there any indication that this package uses its own matplotlibrc file? If not, try changing your usual matplotlibrc, as [detailed here](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file).

Comment: [Edit] your question to report about what you have tried. The question itself should contain all information. Comments are meant for providing comments.

Comment: How do you use deepTools? Since I imagine this is not a standard tool which a lot of people know, you need to provide much more information - or you may need to wait a couple of month for some expert to come along to answer this.

Comment: deepTools is just a python based toolkit for analyzing genomic data. In particular I am using a function called plotHeatmap. http://deeptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/plotHeatmap.html

Comment: What I mean is that you need to show **how** you use it. Looking at the documentation this seems to be a command line tool, which has nothing to do with python.